# Navigating chrome://downloads/ page using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom

I am trying to click on the first download in my chrome://downloads/ webpage using Python and the Selenium Chromedriver.  Any suggestions on how to navigate through the Shadow DOMs using Python to access this download.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use execute_script.
For example, this code return name of the last downloaded file:

```
driver.execute_script("""
                var file_name = document.querySelector('downloads-manager')
                    .shadowRoot.getElementById('frb0')
                    .shadowRoot.getElementById('file-link').textContent;
                return file_name;
                """)
```